# Why are Y axis labels offset in ggplot?

Tags: ggplot2, axis-labels

[The Y axis labels are offset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzmeo.png)

The Y axis labels from 100 to the top are aligned to the right, while from 90 to the bottom are aligned to the left. I've looked at many paramaters and I couldn't find one to be causing this. Also, I haven't found anyone else with this same issue.

Here's my code:

```
test <- ggplot(data,
  aes(x=Month, y=Value, color=Name, group=Name, fill=Name))+
  geom_line(size=3)+
  geom_point(size=5)+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#FBE785","#0F5F00","#FFC300","#1BFFAA"))+
  ylab ("")+
  xlab ("")+
  labs(caption = paste("Fonte: Fred e IBGE.")) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b/%y", breaks = "6 month", expand=c(0,0))+
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")+
  theme_minimal() +
  guides(fill=guide_legend())+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill= "#122929",color = "#122929"),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#122929"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "#4D4B55", size =0.1),
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(color= "#4D4B55", size =0.1),
        panel.grid = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(vjust = 1, hjust=-1),
        axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = -1, hjust=0),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.key.width  = unit(1.5, "cm"),
        plot.caption = element_text(family = "Abel",vjust = -1, hjust = 0,colour="#4D4B55", size= 30),
        text = element_text(family = "Abel", color = "#4D4B55",size = 35),
        plot.margin = margin(1,1,1.5,1.2, "cm"))

ggsave("./test.png", width = 21, height = 15, dpi = 300)
```

PS: Not sharing the data itself because I guess that's not where the problem is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text is misaligned because of your `axis.text.y` argument. Change `hjust` to 1 and it will be properly aligned. I have provided a minimal reproducible example below.

```
library(tidyverse)
Month <- rep(x = month.abb, times = 10)
Value <- sample(x = 10:120, size = 120, replace = TRUE)
Name <- sample(x = LETTERS[1:4], size = 120, replace = TRUE)
data <- data.frame(Month, Value, Name)

ggplot(data, aes(x = Month, y = Value, color = Name, group = Name, fill = Name)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) + geom_point(size = 2) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(vjust = 1, hjust = 1)) # <- problem here
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I had set it like that because with hjust = 1 the labels get too close to the plot border and I wanted it to be further apart. I guess I'll have to find another way to move them.

Comment: You can always set `hjust` to be a decimal number, so you can play around with it until it looks right.

Comment: I managed to get it right by adding `margin=margin(0,20,0,0)` to `axis.text.y`. Thanks again!